# TargetParameterCountException on Application.Exit

Tags: c#, forms, exit

I am trying to close my C# Form application from a different thread than the main thread. I always get this error:
'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
on the main line in Program.cs:

```
Application.Run(new Im_SecurityCenter(args));
```

I have tried doing it through this.BeginInvoke(ShutdownDelegate) and also using a dispatcher, but always the same error.

Comment: Let's see the line with which you're trying to close the app.

Comment: dispatcher.Invoke(DShutdown, DispatcherPriority.Normal);

and 

this.BeginInvoke(DShutdown);

Both are delegates that call System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit(). I know the delegates are setup properly as I use them in many other places in the project with no issues.

Comment: I should also add that I get the same error when trying to call Close() on the form

Comment: @IanDubya: Please put your code into your original question. Putting additional code into the comments section makes it VERY hard to read. (Same with the stack trace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception indicates a problem with the Invoke call.

Use the Threads window to find the true source of the Exception. The cited line is not the source.

Ensure that the late-bound method being invoked has the same number of parameters as you are passing in your .Invoke